# Why does axios/mongodb findOneAndReplace call work when updating page location, but returns undefined whenever an additional field is added to object?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, mongoose, axios

please provide any pointers you can to the code in general, I am new to React.

The application here creates new cards ("pages") on a blackboard, when a page is dragged anywhere on the blackboard a call to the mongodb database calls a findOneAndReplace to replace that page with a new page state with the new coordinates. This way the page locations persist on the blackboard after the app is closed.
In addition, the user can drag widgets onto each page, which are also saved as an array of objects in the page card's state and in the database.

I have spent a few nights and cannot debug this issue.
If I drag a page, add a page or delete a page, the state updates fine and the database call updates fine.
If I drag one or more widgets onto a page, the state updates fine with a new widget object array, and it shows up fine on the app.
But, the POST call to mongodb returns with 'undefined'.
What is most weird, is after that, if I drag the page anywhere, it then starts calling back undefined, and that page starts behaving strangely.
Any page without a widget works absolutely fine though.

I have tried to get more from the error than just 'undefined'. But the post method doesn't seem to call at all once there is a widget field added into the page object. I've tried adding console logs within the POST method, but they aren't printed within the post function after a widget is added, even before the findOneAndReplace call.

This is what the page object looks like when successfully passed to the post method (before any widgets are dragged onto the page)

[image: Page object passed to findOneAndReplace]

This is what the page object looks like after a few widgets are added, any call to post and update the page just returns with 'undefined' using the same post method used when the page moves

[image: Failed post method when updating a widget]

What is also even more alarming, is the pages x and y coordinates shift slightly when a widget is dragged onto it...

I'm really not sure if there is some fighting going on between the widget state being updated within the page component and the state of the page on the 'pagetree' blackboard, or whether I'm doing something wrong with Axios perhaps?

Please help if you can!
Happy to post full code if you need it
Thanks

**Widget callback method and onDragEnd method on the pageCard component (the component sitting on the blackboard)**

```
const updateWidgets = useCallback((newWidgets) => {
    setWidgets(newWidgets);
      }, [widgets]);

function handleOnDragEnd(result) {
    if (!result.destination) return;
    const items = Array.from(widgets);
    const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
    setWidgets(items);
    widgetCallback(items,_id);
  }
```

**Code for the pageTree (page blackboard) parent component which makes calls to the API**

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PageCard from './PageCard';
import { useDrop } from "react-dnd";
import { ItemTypes } from "../Utils/items";
import Api from "../api.js"

const styles = {
  width: 1000,
  height: 3000,
  border: '1px solid black',
  position: 'relative',
};

function PageTree({AddNewPageFunc}) {
  const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
  const updatePage = useCallback((droppedPage) => {
  const updatedPages = pages.map(page => droppedPage._id == page._id ? droppedPage : page);
  //console.log("updated pages ",updatedPages);
  setPages(updatedPages);
  //console.log("set pages ",pages);
    }, [pages]);

  const [{isOver}, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: ItemTypes.PAGECARD,
        drop(page, monitor) {
            const delta = monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset();
            let x = Math.round(page.x + delta.x);
            let y = Math.round(page.y + delta.y);
            page.x = x;
            page.y = y;
            page.widgets = [{name: "widget", thing: "widgetthing", header: "otherWidgetThing"}];
            savePage(page, page._id);
            updatePage(page);
            return undefined;
        },
    }), [updatePage]);

    const savePage = (pageDetails, id) => {
        console.log("function called to update page: ",pageDetails);
        Api.withToken().post('/pageupdate/'+id,
            pageDetails
        ).then(function (response) {
            console.log("?worked ",response.data)
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log("page save failed for some reason: ",error.response);
        });
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
      AddNewPageFunc.current = AddNewPage
    }, [pages])

    const AddNewPage = useCallback(() => {
      Api.withToken().post('/addblankpage/'
        ).then(function (response) {
          console.log("produced: ",response.data);
          setPages([...pages,response.data])
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
    }, [pages]);

    const handleDeletedCallback = useCallback((deletedIndex) => {
      //I HAVE NO IDEA WHY I HAVE TO CALL SETPAGES TWICE, BUT THAT IS THE RULES, IT WON'T WORK IF YOU DON'T...
      setPages(pages.splice(deletedIndex, 1));
      setPages(pages);
    }, [pages]);

    const WidgetAddCallback = (widgets, pageID) => {
      console.log("widget callback fired requesting widgets ",widgets," for ID ",pageID)
      const newPageIndex = pages.findIndex(page => page._id === pageID);
      const updatedPage = Object.assign(pages[newPageIndex], {widgets: widgets});
      console.log("updated page is ",updatedPage)
      savePage(updatedPage, pageID);
      updatePage(updatedPage);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      Api.withToken().get('/pages/') //can add in a prop to return only a given tree once the app gets bigger
      .then(res => {
        setPages(res.data);
      })
    }, []);

  return (
      <div ref={drop} style={styles}>
          {pages.map((page, index) => (<PageCard page={page} id={page._id} key={page._id} index={index} widgetCallback ={WidgetAddCallback} deleteCallback={handleDeletedCallback} handleMaximise={() => handleMaximise(page)} handleCopy={() => handleCopy(page)}/>))}
      </div>
      )
}

export default PageTree;
```

**The API file for using axios**

```
import axios from 'axios';
const baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3001"

export default {
  noToken() {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: baseURL
    });
  },
  
  withToken() {
    const tokenStr = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token")
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: baseURL,
      headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${tokenStr}`}
    });
  } 
}
```

**The POST method for updating a page, which no longer calls at all whenever a widget is added**

```
const express = require('express')
const router =new express.Router()
const Pages = require('../models/page')
const auth = require('../middleware/authentication')

router.post('/pageupdate/:_id',auth, async(req,res)=>{
    //console.log("received for pageUpdate API: ",req.body);
    const query = { "_id": req.params };
    const replacementPage = req.body;
    const options = { "returnNewDocument": false };
    Pages.findOneAndReplace(query, replacementPage, null, function (err, doc) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            console.log("replaced successfully");
        }})
})
```

Comment: I don't think this will fix your problem, but when you're only updating a document, you should use `findOneAndUpdate()`, instead of `findOneAndReplace()` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: Nope it didn't fix the issue, but all the same, I've updated with a findOneAndUpdate to update only updated params with a page state change. Thanks for taking a look